# How can I determine why my ASP.NET application is recycling

Tags: asp.net, iis, session

I am running an ASP.NET application on an IIS7 server. It has been running fine for a long time, but over the past week or so it has been discarding all users' sessions several times a day. I enabled all of the application pool recycle logging options as described in http://blogs.iis.net/ganekar/archive/2008/12/12/iis-7-0-application-pool-recycles-log-a-event-in-windows-event-log.aspx, but I didn't get anything in my event log.

There are no errors in the event log, and no visible symptoms except that all my users lose their sessions.

Are there any other reasons that IIS would recycle my application pool? Is there any other type of logging that I can enable to find out what is happening?

Comment: I found some more information. I wrote a script to log the IIS worker process ID every hour. The session problem happened again this morning, but when I checked the log, it showed that the process ID is still the same. So, it doesn't look like this is happening because of a worker process restarting.

Comment: I loaded Process Monitor on the server, and used the instructions from http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx to write an event log entry every time the application ends. It happened again today, and the logged message was "Directory rename change notification for 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\'. JobTraQ dir change or directory rename." Process Monitor showed a lot of "NotifyChangeDirectory" events, but I can't tell where they came from.

Answer (score 7):

When you experience this behavior, how recently have you done a deployment of your files to the server?

There is a nasty configuration option called numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart on the compilation tag:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="15">
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.compilationsection.numrecompilesbeforeapprestart.aspx

This value defaults to 15. I've been through an application killing all user sessions before and this was the culprit for me. For roughly a day after a lightly used web application was updated (new files copied to the server; this ended up overwriting EVERY file, numbering into the hundreds), we'd get constant AppDomain restarts evidenced by all Session values for all users disappearing.

I found this bug report listing the behavior I'm experiencing:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319947

Here is the really important relevant text to my scenario:

> However, this problem occurs when you
>   load many new .aspx or .ascx files to
>   the server (for example, 61 files).
>   The server unloads the application
>   when the first 15 files are recompiled
>   and every time another 15 files are
>   recompiled until the server reaches
>   61. This results in four application restarts even though only one is
>   required.

I switched the value to 99999 and the problem went away. This means more memory will build up in my worker process, so I added a daily recycle (3am when my site has no users) to the IIS AppPool recycle settings.

Comment: Hopefully now that it's on SO, it'll be easier to find via Google.

Comment: That was an interesting article, but my problem is different. That bug seems to involve multiple application restarts in a short period of time after a large update. Our last update was about a week ago, and the restarts seem to happen over longer time spans.

Comment: "Short" is relative... when it happened to me, it would easily last an entire day, occasionally it would *seem* to last longer. We'd update a couple hundred pages, which wouldn't all get used for quite a while. As the users explored larger parts of the application, application restarts would occur. We'd get one in the morning, then hours later get another, then at night get another. Depending on the size of the update and # of pages and controls, the problem can persist for quite a while.

Comment: So, in your case, the restarts would be triggered whenever a user hit a page that had not been hit since the update?

Comment: Correct, and it seemed random. Say we'd update 90 ASPX and ASCX pages... as the users slowly explored the site as the day went on (it is a lightly used site), on ASPX/ASCX file #15 the site would restart. And so on. Sometimes they would happen over two days (no customers using the site those days - this happens occasionally), and other times they'd all happen in 2-3 hours and it would work for another week without problem.

If I were you, I'd bump that value in your config just to rule it out (include an AppPool restart with your update).

Comment: @Adam Sills I have made a test . I created a page named `me.aspx` which has a submit button . when I click it I check if `session["aaa"]` exists if not - I'm creating one. then I uploaded `another` file named `1.aspx` 20 times ( overwrite - the same file). However - I still was able to read the session. so it didnt make any recycle . is it because i have uploaded the same file ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: First, my answer was written over 2 years ago and behaviors can change. Second, I'm pretty sure ASP.NET won't recompile unless you change the content of your page(s). Third, I think you need multiple pages, not one page changing constantly (see the text I quoted indicating as much). Fourth, see my links above (the link to the MSDN bug) and if you're having a specific issue, write an actual question on SO or contact Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You can set options in the metabase to log the different types of recycle events to the event log.

For IIS 6.0, see http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/87892589-4eda-4003-b4ac-3879eac4bf48.mspx

For example, to enable logging of recycle events due to exceeding the private memory limitation, execute this on your web server:

```
cd %systemroot%\inetpub\adminscripts
cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set w3svc/AppPools/YOUR_APP_POOL_NAME/AppPoolRecyclePrivateMemory true
```

Here is a link to [different] instructions for IIS 7.0: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771318%28v=ws.10%29.aspx